# Как найти путь из суммы чисел равный данному числу в двумерном массиве?

Tags: java, алгоритм

В общем нужно сделать рекурсивный метод

```
public static boolean findSum (int mat[][], int sum, int path[][])
```

Первый параметр это двумерный произвольно заполненый целыми положительными числами. Второй параметр это данная сумма из которой нужно собрать путь в двумерном масиве(первый параметр). Третий параметр это двумерный масив который имеет такой же размер как и первый параметр, но инициализирован нулями. В этот масив и нужно записать путь из первого параметра(двумерного масива).

Если путь не найден, то метод возвращает `false` и `path` остается заполнен нулями. Если найдено более одного пути то любой из них выбрать и метод возвращает `true`. Если найден только один возможный путь то он должен быть записан в `path` и метод возвращает `true`

Пример

Дан массив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сумма дана 4

метод возвращает `true` и один из вариантов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Я пробую решить с вот такой комбинацией

```
int[][] mat1 = {
            {1,1,1,1},
            {100,100,100,1},
            {100,100,100,1},
            {1,1,1,1}
        };

int[][] path1 = {
            {0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0}
        };


findSum(mat1,600,path1)
```

Как можно решить вот такую задачу?

Я думал сделать циклами которые сначала будут провераять все горизонтали потом вертикали, но тогда это не будет рекурсивно и врядли это будет работать, потом думал делать рекурсивно брать из `mat` первых два числа и если их сумма меньше чем данная `sum`, то вызывать метод рекурсивно в теми же параметрами кроме `sum` которая должна быть типо `sum - result`, но тогда я не смогу возвращаться обратно если нужно будет проверять следующие значения...

В общем подскажите по какому пути двигаться

Comment: Поиск всех путей в графе...

Comment: метод обязательно должен быть рекурсивным?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я в графах не силен, но брутфорс решение накидал (правда, на C#)

```
public static bool findSum(int[,] mat, int sum, int[,] path)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
            if (findSum(mat, sum, path, i, j)) return true;
    return false;
}

public static bool findSum(int[,] mat, int sum, int[,] path, int i, int j)
{   
    if (sum < 0) return false;
    if (i < 0 || i >= mat.GetLength(0)) return false;
    if (j < 0 || j >= mat.GetLength(1)) return false;
    if (path[i, j] == 1) return false;
    if (sum == 0) return true;

    path[i, j] = 1;

    if (findSum(mat, sum - mat[i, j], path, i - 1, j)) return true;
    if (findSum(mat, sum - mat[i, j], path, i, j - 1)) return true;
    if (findSum(mat, sum - mat[i, j], path, i + 1, j)) return true;
    if (findSum(mat, sum - mat[i, j], path, i, j + 1)) return true;

    path[i, j] = 0;

    return false;
}
```

Проверял вот так

```
var mat = new int[,] {
    {1, 1, 1, 1},
    {100, 100, 100, 1},
    {100, 100, 100, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1},
};

var path = new int[,] {
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
};

Console.WriteLine(findSum(mat, 600, path));
path.Dump("path");
```

Результат вот такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: O(много), но сработает, +1 :)